# Is “It was been there, done that” grammatically correct?

Tags: word-usage, past-tense, present-perfect

Is it correct to say "it was been"?

I was texting to someone about the Apollo moon-landing, someone asked why they don't fly to the moon anymore and his answer was,

> "**It was been** there, done that."

Meaning why would they do it again if they already did it before"

But I thought the correct way to say it was, "**It has been** there." After some research on this website, I found out that the word "has"  means it still applies today (which in my case it doesn't) and the word "was" means it no longer applies. I think that "was" was used with the wrong words.

Comment: No, it is _never_ correct. Please check the answers associated with the tags that I have added.

Comment: In reference to the Apollo landing on the moon, I would say "it has been there" sounds  off to me. Can you provide a bit more context? Were you saying "where" the spaceship had landed" In which case, I'd point to the night sky and exclaim `It was there where they landed!`

Comment: Someone asked that person why they don't fly to the moon anymore, and his answer was,"It was been there, done that." Meaning why would they do it again if they already did it before.

Comment: IF they said that it was “been-there, done-that”, then you've misparsed the sentence; just because *was* and *been* occurred together there doesn’t mean that *was been* was somehow a syntactic constituent. It wasn't. It was just an unhappy accident.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The phrase needed quotation marks

> It was "been there, done that"

This is indeed said when someone claims an event or deed (e.g. landing on the moon)  has already been performed

> *[been there done that](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/been_there,_done_that)*
>    an assertion that the speaker has personal experience or knowledge of a particular place or topic quotations
>   A: *Paragliding?* 
>   B: **Been there, done that**, bought the T-shirt.